# В каком случае стоит переносить Broadcast receiver в Dagger

Tags: android, dagger2

У меня есть BroadcastReceiver, суть которого крайне проста - запускать сервис приложения,отвечающий за треккинг локации после его перезагрузки.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, LocationCheckService.class));
    }
}
```

Он прописан только в манифесте, больше нигде не указывается. Стоит ли его переносить в даггер, ведь тут есть context?

Comment: А что вы собрались тут инжектить даггером?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Application Context, как минимум

Comment: Зачем? В вашем случае Context только для запуска сервиса используется. Не усложняйте себе жизнь, и тем кто после вас будет сопровождать проект.